# Ignite [SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected

Tags: node.js, ignite

I have ignite on single node with persistence enabled with two caches one contains 60 millions records, and another contains around 20k records.When i request from smaller cache data it gives results as expected however on larger cache data gives following error:

> [SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [threadName=partition-exchanger, blockedFor=10s][12:32:21,772][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1573628531076]]]

what should I do?

Comment: Can you share complete log? What kind of request do you do?

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing is about [health check and failure handlers](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling#section-critical-workers-health-check)

If you perform a full scan over a large table it could take a while.
If you store complex objects, then probably you do not need to request all fields, etc.

Could you clarify, what query do you use and share cluster configuration?
The logs are welcome as well.

Comment: I have a similar issue here with logs from both server and client sides: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624177/blocked-system-critical-thread-has-been-detected